# Asynchronous HttpModule MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, async-await, httpmodule

I have a synchronous HttpModule that contains the following code.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs as the first event in the HTTP pipeline chain of execution 
    /// when ASP.NET responds to a request.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">An <see cref="T:System.EventArgs">EventArgs</see> that 
    /// contains the event data.</param>
    private async void ContextBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext context = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;
        await this.ProcessImageAsync(context);
    }
```

When I try to run the module from an empty MVC4 application (NET 4.5) I get the following error.

> An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous
>   operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or
>   module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this
>   exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is
>   marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>.

I'm missing something it seems but by my reading that the error shouldn't actually occur.

I've had a dig around but I cannot seem to find anything to help, does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So you have asynchronous code in a synchronous HttpModule event handler, and ASP.NET throws an exception indicating that asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler/module. Seems pretty straightforward to me.

To fix this, you should not subscribe to `BeginRequest` directly; instead, create a `Task`-returning "handler", wrap it in [`EventHandlerTaskAsyncHelper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.eventhandlertaskasynchelper.aspx), and pass it to [`AddOnBeginRequestAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d929d82.aspx).

Something like this:

```
private async Task ContextBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  HttpContext context = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;
  await ProcessImageAsync(context);

  // Side note; if all you're doing is awaiting a single task at the end of an async method,
  //  then you can just remove the "async" and replace "await" with "return".
}
```

and to subscribe:

```
var wrapper = new EventHandlerTaskAsyncHelper(ContextBeginRequest);
application.AddOnBeginRequestAsync(wrapper.BeginEventHandler, wrapper.EndEventHandler);
```

Comment: This must be a few times you've helped me now, Thanks! 
I should have said sorry, The code is actually written in Net 4.0 and uses the BCL libraries to support the async keyword so I could support both 4.0 and 4.5. As such EventHandlerTaskAsyncHelper isn't available to me.

Comment: Ah, unfortunately, `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` has [undefined behavior on ASP.NET 4.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework.aspx). On ASP.NET, you *have* to run on .NET 4.5, not .NET 4.0.

Comment: Ah ok... So, testing this if I remove the `targetFramework="4.5"` from the `<httpRuntime />` node in the web.config this works. Does that mean that in NET 4.0 my httpModule is not, in fact, asynchronous? Does that also mean that I cannot use an asynchronous httpModule without `EventHandlerTaskAsyncHelper` with MVC or is there another way. I'm still a shade confused that it is throwing an error to be honest. The message seems to say that httpModules are ok.

Comment: I believe you're defining "works" as "does not throw an exception". Take another look at the blog post: if you are writing ASP.NET on .NET 4.0, then you *cannot* use `async` (`Microsoft.Bcl.Async` does *not* reverse this). Some core pieces of ASP.NET were rewritten in .NET 4.5 to support `async` properly (in particular the `SynchronizationContext`), which are simply not available on .NET 4.0.

Comment: I think I've been looking at this all the wrong way. BCL simply allows compilation with the async keyword to then but ignores it's behaviour then? So theoretically I should be able to build it in Net 4.5, use conditional #if statements to wrap your NET 4.5 sample and support NET 4.0 With my existing code?

Comment: BCL provides the core (.NET) behavior, but ASP.NET has its own behavior that it needs (and BCL doesn't provide). So `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` will bring full `async` support to .NET 4.0 desktop apps, but not ASP.NET apps. If you need to support both, then compile-time conditionals are one approach.